# Cannot delete jenkins docker old persistent data in windows 10 wsl,

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I am a beginner of devops tech. I have a running Jenkins/docker container on a linux box and want to move to a windows 10 pro machine. To prepare for the migration, I tested the docker desktop and run the jenkins:lts image successfully with some test user and config.

When i tried to delete the test container and recreate a fresh one so I can move the jenkins live data to there, the window docker continue to find old configure file of the test jenkins container.

I have deleted the docker completely a few times, including all wsl2 related folder, also deleted any docker things in user/appdata folder. But when I recreate the jenkins container, it still able to find some old configure and show me this.

```
hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /var/jenkins_home found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
```

I tried below command but still not able to (1) locate and (2) remove the old config. One remark, when I reinstall the docker, and the first time I build the jenkins container, there is no tmp file inside the \wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes created.

So the old docker config must be somewhere. Thanks for helping.

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate -V
docker-compose down -v
```

My docker-compose file is here. Thanks for helping

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
      - ~/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

volumes:
  jenkins:
    driver: local
```

Comment: After deleting, did you also remove Docker resources you created? Such as with `docker system prune`?

Comment: @tentative No I did not and tried after reading your comment, it works. Many thanks!

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I added a bit more explanation about why that worked in an answer. Glad it solved your issue!

Answer (score 1):

In your `docker-compose` file, you created resources that were cached even after removing your old config file and images. Removing the docker image will only make you re-pull or re-create the `jenkins/jenkins:lts` image. The `--force-recreate` flag will only rebuild containers if their configuration had not changed.

However, you needed to run `docker system prune` to remove unused resources (such as the `jenkins` volume which needed to be explicitly removed). Here are the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) for this command. Alternatively, you could have run `docker system prune -a --volumes` to remove just the unused volumes, leaving in place any other networks or other resources.